# Mounting Ikea Cabinet not able to mount directly to studs

Tags: wood, studs

I'm trying to mount a set of Ikea Knoxhult cabinets (37lb for each cabinet) to a garage wall but the mounting brackets don't align with the studs.

Have 2 options in mind.

A pair of toggle bolts for each cabinet. Toggle bolt is rated for 137lbs each. Could also add corner mounting brackets to the bottom corners to add a second set of toggle bolts.

Mount a horizontal (2x4? 1x4?) and attach to the 3 studs and and then mount the cabinet to the horizontal piece. Would need a matching horizontal piece to match wall depth at the bottom and could also add mounting brackets to the bottom corners and attach.

Is option 1 safe enough for the weight of the cabinets plus whatever would go inside?

For option 2, what screw types would I need? I have some #10 zinc Phillips head screws. Would that work? Length wise I would just need to get halfway into the studs for the mounted wood and halfway into the mounted wood when attaching the cabinet?

[image]

For 2x4 mount to wall studs: 6x 4 inch screws?

For Cabinet to mount: 2x or 4x 1 inch screws?

Comment: The 137# capacity. Is that withdrawal strength or shear strength? It must be predicated on the wall material. Does your drywall material match their test wall's material?

Answer (score 4):

If Ikea is close to where you are, get the suspension rail they make ([SEKTION](https://www.ikea.com/ca/en/assembly_instructions/sektion-suspension-rail-galvanized__AA-1054038-7-100.pdf)) for this application. You mount it to the wall so that it spans across the studs. Use toggle bolts on the ends if needed. You then hang the cabinet from the rail and secure it through the holes at each bracket (two per cabinet). This will keep the cabinet tight up against the wall.

Or mount a 2x2 to the wall along the bottom so the cabinets sit on the 2x2. This will take the majority of the weight. Then, you can use toggle bolts at the top brackets.

Comment: Also, based on the apparent location of the cabinet, OP could simply get a couple of 3/4" boards and screw them across the studs, and mount the cabinet to those.

Answer (score 2):

Toggle bolts might hold 137#, but will the drywall hold that much.

Use the 2x4s, 1x4s might be enough, but why worry.  A section of 3/4 plywood will work also.

You want the wood at top and bottom of the cabinet.  An extra piece at the centre does not hurt.

You want at least 1.5 inches into the studs adding 1/2 inch for drywall, more is better but need to watch out for cables/pipes(if everything done to code).

Comment: Thank you. Is there a best screw type to use?? Never done anything like this before so I have no idea.